# how to set c flag to 0

Tags: arm

I'm writing a program in arm in which I have to get the bits of a register. My idea is make left logical shift and then look the value of c flag. The problem is if the value shifted is 0 the c flag is unchanged. 
So how to set the C to 0.

my program contain :

```
lsl r1, r1, #1
bcs bit_1
b bit_0
```

Maybe there are better solution.

Comment: _"The problem is if the value shifted is 0 the c flag is unchanged"_ Huh? It should be set to the last bit shifted out, which in this case would be 0.

Comment: If you code is **ARM**, then you need to use the `lsls` form; which sets the condition codes.  I believe it is an alias to `movs`.  You should specify if you are ARM, thumb, thumb2, etc.

Comment: I use ARM thumb2. did lsls modify c flag and if yes when and how it modify it?